# Downloading all JS files using Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to crawl a website searching for all JS files to download them.
I am new to Scrapy and I have found that I can use CrawlSpider but seems I have an issue with LinkExtractors as my parser is not executed.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class JSDownloader(CrawlSpider):
  name = 'jsdownloader'
  allowed_domains = ['example.com']
  start_urls = ['http://example.com']


  rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('\.js', )), callback='parse_item'),
  ))

  def parse_item(self, response):
    self.logger.info('JS File %s', response.url)
    item = scrapy.Item()
    # Process Item here
    yield item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that LinkExtractor has tags and attrs parameters where the default are for 'a' and 'area' tags only. [LinxExtractor Documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html)

So the solution is to add '' tag:

```
Rule(LinkExtractor(tags=('a', '<script>'), attrs('href','src')), callback='parse_item'),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract all the `script` tags and do a simple filter to get the js files.

Try this:

```py
import scrapy

class JSDownloader(scrapy.Spider):
  name = 'jsdownloader'
  allowed_domains = ['example.com']
  start_urls = ['http://example.com']

  def parse(self, response):
    hrefs = response.xpath('//script/@href').extract()
    js_links = [href for href in hrefs if href.endswith('.js')]

    # do stuff with the list of js links here, i.e fetch and download them
    
    yield {'js_links': js_links}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I want to reach to JS files which used in <script> tags not <a> tags.

Comment: I updated the answer to look for script tags instead, should work the same way